# How to recurse with dot notation?

Tags: scheme

I have a function:

```
(define (func lst . conditions)
    ; do something
    (func (cdr lst) conditions))
```

But the second time, it seems like `func` wraps `conditions` inside a list and then I can't use its content (functions) properly. How should I pass `conditions` so that the function will treat it the same way as it is treated with the initial call to `func`?

Comment: Use `(apply func (cdr lst) conditions)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not entirely accurate. To quote from R5RS, chapter 4.1.4 (emphasis mine):

`(<variable1> ... <variablen> . <variablen+1>)`: *If a space-delimited period precedes the last variable, then the procedure takes n or more arguments, where n is the number of formal arguments before the period (there must be at least one). The value stored in the binding of the last variable will be **a newly allocated list** of the actual arguments left over after all the other actual arguments have been matched up against the other formal arguments.*

In other words, `conditions` is a list from the very start. Check it by defining something like:

```
(define (func lst . conditions)
  (display conditions) (newline))
```

As Alexis King correctly points out, you need to use `apply` to "unwrap" the list again:

```
(apply func (cdr lst) conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not called dot notation, but a rest argument. Basically the rest of the arguments is consed to a list.

The opposite of a rest argument would be a procedure that takes a list as it's last argument as if the elements were the extra arguments to the function. One generic such exists as `apply`.

```
(define (double-list . e)
  (if (null? e)
      '()
      (list* (car e) 
             (car e)
             (apply helper (cdr e)))))
```

However if you have a 10 element list you end up making 10 lists of decreasing size that only lives for a short while before being passed as arguments. Keeping the first list would be better and one could do this with a helper:

```
(define (double-list . e)
  (define (helper e)
    (if (null? e)
        '()
        (list* (car e) 
               (car e)
               (helper (cdr e)))))
  (helper e))
```

It works the same, but with less used memory since the helper just iterates the first created list instead of creating a new list for each iteration.